# How to aggregate logs from several Jenkins Jobs\Pipelines in one place?

Tags: jenkins, logging, error-logging, datadog

Our project is responsible for migrating data from one system to another. We are going to run transformation, validation and migration scripts using Jenkins.

It's unclear for me how to aggregate logs from several Jobs or Pipelines in Jenkins. How it can be done?

We'll rely on logs heavily to identify any issues found during validation etc.

In terms of our planned setup we'll have AWS EC2 instances + we can use Datadog (our company uses it). Can we use Datadog for this purpose?

Comment: We use Logstash for something similar to this. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference [this doc](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging) to find where the default logging path is for Jenkins depending on your OS. (For linux, it's `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` if you don't configure it to be something else.

Then as long as your [Datadog agent](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/?tab=agentv6) is v6+ you can use the Datadog agent to tail your jenkins.log file by following [this doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=tailexistingfiles#tail-existing-files).

Specifically, you'd add this line to your `dadatod.yaml`:

```
logs_enabled: true
```

and add this content to any old `conf.yaml` file nested in your `conf.d/` directory, such as `conf.d/jenkins.d/conf.yaml`:

```
logs:
  - type: file
    path: /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
    service: jenkins
    source: jenkins
```

Then the agent will tail your log file as it's written to, and will forward it to your Datadog account so you can query, graph, and monitor on your log data there.

Once you have the logs coming in, you may want to write a [processing pipeline](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/) to get the critical attributes parsed out, but that would be material for a new question :) .